# Vector field defined by constant function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-fields

Let $n \geq 2$. Given $\phi:[0,\infty] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ continuously differetiable and $F:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ a vector field, 
Defined as $F(x) = \phi(\|x\|_2)$. Prove that $F$ is conservative if and only if $\phi$ is constant.
Already proved that $\phi$ is constant implies $F$ conservative.
I'm struggling with proving the other direction.

$F$ conservative $\Longrightarrow$ $\phi$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi(x)=(\phi_1(x),\ldots\phi_n(x))$. Also, let $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(F_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\ldots,F_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n))$ where we have:

$$F_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\phi_i(\rho)$$

where $\rho=\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\|_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$. Now, if $\rho\gt 0$, we have:

$$\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\phi_i'(\rho)\frac{x_j}{\rho}$$

Assuming $F$ is conservative, which implies $\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i}$, we have:

$$\phi_i'(\rho)x_j=\phi_j'(\rho)x_i$$

This also means:

$$\phi_i'(\rho)x_j=\phi_j'(\rho)(-x_i)$$

(swap $x_i$ with $-x_i$, which gives the same $\rho$).

Adding those last two equalities, we conclude $\phi_i'(\rho)x_j=0$, and as for any $\rho\gt 0$ we can choose non-zero $x_j$'s, it follows that $\phi_i'=0$ i.e. $\phi_i$ is constant. (On $(0,+\infty)$, and so by continuity on $[0,+\infty)$.)

Hence, $\phi$ is constant and $F$ is constant.

Comment: I can't understand why it works : ϕ′i(ρ)xj=ϕ′j(ρ)(−xi) "(swap xi with −xi, which gives the same ρ)."

Comment: @Eran If this identity is valid for all $(x_1\,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_n)$ (okay, we have deliberately excluded $(0,0,\ldots,0)$, then it is valid for $(x_1\,\ldots,-x_i,\ldots,x_n)$ (and the same $\rho$). Maybe it will help you to expand $\rho$ in the calculation, as it is, after all, just $\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_i^2+\cdots+x_n^2}=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+(-x_i)^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$...

Comment: How can I show that if F is constant then it is also conservative?

Comment: @Eran Ahm... didn't you say in your question that you have already solved that problem?

Comment: @Eran Okay... If $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(F_1,\ldots,F_n)$, take $G(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=F_1x_1+\cdots+F_nx_n$ and $F$ will be the gradient of $G$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71024/discussion-between-eran-and-user8734617).

Answer (score 0):

Talking in terms of differential forms, if $F$ is conservative then it is closed. Thus you know that

$$0=\frac{\partial F_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}-\frac{\partial F_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}=\phi_{i}^{\prime}\frac{\partial\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}}{\partial x_{j}}-\phi_{j}^{\prime}\frac{\partial\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}}{\partial x_{i}}=$$

$$=\phi_{i}^{\prime}\frac{x_{j}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}}-\phi_{j}^{\prime}\frac{x_{i}}{\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}}$$

$$\Longrightarrow x_{j}\phi_{i}^{\prime}-x_{i}\phi_{j}^{\prime}=0$$

for every $1\leq i,j\leq n$. That's true on the sphere $\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=R>0$, *i.e.*

$$x_{j}\phi_{i}^{\prime}\left(R\right)-x_{i}\phi_{j}^{\prime}\left(R\right)=0$$

where $\phi_{i}^{\prime}\left(R\right)$ and $\phi_{j}^{\prime}\left(R\right)$ are constants. But this is true for every value of $x_{i},x_{j}$ as long as $\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}=R$ (you can argue that there are multiple choices for every $n\geq 2$), and hence you must have

$$\phi_{i}^{\prime}\left(R\right)=0$$

for every $R>0$ and $1\leq i\leq n$. Combine this to get

$$\phi^{\prime}=0 \Longrightarrow \phi=\rm const.$$

on $[0,\infty)$ (the $R=0$ case follows from continuity).